# Twitter Stream not working for Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Using the code below, I'm trying to get a hash tag. It works fine for larger searches like #StarWars, but when i ask for smaller ones it doesn't seem to return anything.

Ideas?

*'code' is used instead of the actual strings for authentication*

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from textwrap import TextWrapper
import json

access_token = "code"
access_token_secret = "code"
consumer_key = "code"
consumer_secret = "code"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    ''' Handles data received from the stream. '''

    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', subsequent_indent='    ')

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print self.status_wrapper.fill(status.text)
            print '\n %s  %s  via %s\n' % (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.source)
        except:
            # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
            # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('Got an error with status code: ' + str(status_code))
        return True # To continue listening

    def on_timeout(self):
        print('Timeout...')
        return True # To continue listening

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=['#TestingPythonTweet'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so found that the answer to this is that i was expecting it to work retro-actively. This was a fundamental error on my part. Instead what actually happens is that it gets what's *currently* being tweeted. Not was has been previously.